# What is the Islamic way of killing a rat?

Tags: sharia, animals

It may sounds stupid, but now comes to a point that, certain way of killing rat is rather... very inhumane (at least looks like), for example, those traditional flipping traps. But now people call those sticker trap as inhumane as well...

I wonder Islamically, is there such idea that about inhumane on removing / killing the harmful animals?

On the other hand, do mice and rate consider harmful in Islam?

Jazaklahir

Comment: There are five animals you can kill and rat is included in them. Read **al-Bukhaari, 1828**

Comment: You can choose to not kill rat at all. Capture in trap and abandon to far off place. This is how we do in India.

Answer (score 2):

I have never hear anywhere written in Qur'an or Hadith about how to kill a rat/mice but you can kill it by using poison and then throw it in out of everybody.

Now

> On the other hand, do mice and rat consider harmful in Islam?

**Sahih al-Bukhari 1828**

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "It is not sinful (of a Muhrim) to kill five kinds of animals, namely: the crow, the kite, the mouse, the scorpion and the rabid dog. [source](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/28)

It should cover this question.

Comment: Rats are not mice.

Answer (score 0):

I think,by my opinion,since its a thing that bring diesis or the cause of it (remember the black plague) its batter to kill it fast and not torture it. Killing fast its the best and kind way  u can give. I use poison with the rat i caugh. Not because i like it,because they destroyed the house,eat the foot and infected people with their germ.

I maybe ask about my action by allah when i go `there`,but i do what i must to protect my family from dieing with dieses and watch their health. One bite of those thing can kill you if you leave it or have late treatment (experiance by my sis in law and my cousin who families has been biteen by those things)

Kindness to all creature,kill it kindly,like u kill cow and chiken. Make sure it quick,if u have gun use it,or sword if u brave enough. Just watch that thing from bitten u,their claw have the same germ as their mouth,so becarefull.

Dont listen to people say dont kill it (tell that to the dark age about the death black plauge) because im sure they kill mosquito and ants too for fear of the dieses they brough.(im sure they dont want denggi and fire ants in their home) so we will be ask,but remember,we are sent here to `manage` this world and ourself. If its a threat to the family of course we take action to defend ourself.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam.SE. Answers here must be based on Islamic references (quran, hadith or ijtihad) not personal opinions and specualtions. Please provide substantiate your answer with relevant sources. Also go throw [guidelines on writing answers](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

There is a hadith out there where killing with fire is not permissible, so rule that out, even though Im pretty sure you wouldnt even want to use fire to kill a rat.

There is also a hadith out there about deaths that are considered shahid. These are plagues, drowning, chest pain, stomach infection, being crushed, and some others that I cant recall. It may be weird to mention this but I suppose its because these are horrible ways to die, so perhaps it would be a horrible way for the rat to die as well?
I have heard of a crafty way to kill the rat. Using gases. Im no rat biologist but I do know that we have systems in our body that detects specifically carbon dioxide. That is why when there are people out there suggesting suicide they suggest gases other than carbon dioxide, because dying from carbon dioxide would raise all kinds of alarms in the brain. It would be painful. If you have the money and care enough to spend it, buy Nitrogen gas. Its inert and non toxic, and really has no reason to sound an alarm in the brain of any organism because there is 70% of it in the air. But Nitrogen still pushes away the needed oxygen. Nitrogen kills by suffocation without making the animal be too alarmed. If you dont have the budget go for carbon monoxide (e.g. from a vehicle exhaust). Its a colourless odourless gas that we also cannot detect (our brains detect carbon dioxide, not carbon monoxide). If possible, do it in an open, well ventilated area, but create a box just enough to hold the trap, and duct in the vehicle exhaust into the box. This ensures proper dosage. Let it run for like a few minutes and get away from the area to avoid yourself suffocating